# Basic authentication using HTTPWebRequest

Tags: vb.net

How do I successfully pass username and password to a Rails app. The Rails app makes use of http_basic_authenticate_with. The client is written in VB.Net using .NET framework 4.5. The client makes use of httpwebrequest.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Credentials` property to a new `NetworkCredential`.

Comment: I tried it with no luck. I had request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("testme", "Wpassword!")

Comment: I also tried Dim authorization As String = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("testme:Wpassword!"))
            'request.PreAuthenticate = True
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization)